# Archive::Zip install fails on Strawberry Perl

Tags: windows, perl, perl-module, cpan, strawberry-perl

I installed Strawberry Perl. I then tried to install Archive::Perl module using CPAN, failed.
I then tried installing other modules like Log::Log4perl, successful.

Platform -

```
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 20 subversion 1) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=MSWin32, osvers=6.3, archname=MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
    uname='Win32 strawberry-perl 5.20.1.1 #1 Mon Sep 15 13:26:45 2014 x64'
    config_args='undef'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=undef
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=undef, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='gcc', ccflags =' -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE  -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS-DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields',
    optimize='-s -O2',
    cppflags='-DWIN32'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.8.3', gccosandvers=''
```

Error Summary -

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/02_main.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 47 Failed: 7)
  Failed tests:  25, 32-34, 38, 46-47
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 141 tests but ran 47.
t/03_ex.t                   (Wstat: 1536 Tests: 17 Failed: 6)
  Failed tests:  4, 6, 10, 13-14, 16
  Non-zero exit status: 6
Files=16, Tests=140,  9 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr +  0.13 sys =  0.22 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/16 test programs. 13/140 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
  PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.39.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.39.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Archive::Zip'.
Failed during this command:
 PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.39.tar.gz                : make_test NO
```

Complete install output -

```
cpan> install Archive::Zip
Running install for module 'Archive::Zip'
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\P\PH\PHRED\Archive-Zip-1.39.tar.gz ok
Configuring P/PH/PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.39.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Archive::Zip
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.39.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL make=dmake -- OK
Running make for P/PH/PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.39.tar.gz
cp lib/Archive/Zip/ZipFileMember.pm blib\lib\Archive\Zip\ZipFileMember.pm
cp lib/Archive/Zip/MockFileHandle.pm blib\lib\Archive\Zip\MockFileHandle.pm
cp lib/Archive/Zip/DirectoryMember.pm blib\lib\Archive\Zip\DirectoryMember.pm
cp lib/Archive/Zip/FileMember.pm blib\lib\Archive\Zip\FileMember.pm
cp lib/Archive/Zip/NewFileMember.pm blib\lib\Archive\Zip\NewFileMember.pm
cp lib/Archive/Zip/MemberRead.pm blib\lib\Archive\Zip\MemberRead.pm
cp lib/Archive/Zip/Member.pm blib\lib\Archive\Zip\Member.pm
cp lib/Archive/Zip/Tree.pm blib\lib\Archive\Zip\Tree.pm
cp lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm blib\lib\Archive\Zip\Archive.pm
cp lib/Archive/Zip/FAQ.pod blib\lib\Archive\Zip\FAQ.pod
cp lib/Archive/Zip/BufferedFileHandle.pm blib\lib\Archive\Zip\BufferedFileHandle.pm
cp lib/Archive/Zip.pm blib\lib\Archive\Zip.pm
cp lib/Archive/Zip/StringMember.pm blib\lib\Archive\Zip\StringMember.pm
"C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e cp -- script/crc32 blib\script\crc32
pl2bat.bat blib\script\crc32
  PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.39.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
"C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\li
b', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/01_compile.t ................ ok
t/02_main.t ................... The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
warning: C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -pe "BEGIN{binmode(STDIN);binmode(STDOUT)}" doesn't seem to work, may skip some tests at t/common.p
m line 189.
t/02_main.t ................... 1/141
#   Failed test at t/02_main.t line 95.
#          got: 'testdir/RwLiD4dp9b/'
#     expected: 'testdir\RwLiD4dp9b/'
error: member not found
 at C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Archive-Zip-1.39-UHv240\blib\lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 185.
        Archive::Zip::Archive::extractMember(Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x3123628), "testdir\\RwLiD4dp9b/") called at t/02_main.t line 128

#   Failed test at t/02_main.t line 129.
#          got: '2'
#     expected: '0'

#   Failed test at t/02_main.t line 130.

#   Failed test at t/02_main.t line 133.

#   Failed test at t/02_main.t line 146.
#          got: 'testdir/RwLiD4dp9b/string.txt'
#     expected: 'testdir\RwLiD4dp9b/string.txt'
error: member not found
 at C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Archive-Zip-1.39-UHv240\blib\lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 185.
        Archive::Zip::Archive::extractMember(Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x3123628), "testdir\\RwLiD4dp9b/string.txt") called at t/02_main.t
line 175

#   Failed test at t/02_main.t line 176.
#          got: '2'
#     expected: '0'

#   Failed test at t/02_main.t line 177.
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at t/common.pm line 163.
# Looks like you planned 141 tests but ran 47.
# Looks like you failed 7 tests of 47 run.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 just after 47.
t/02_main.t ................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 101/141 subtests
        (less 3 skipped subtests: 37 okay)
t/03_ex.t ..................... The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
warning: C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -pe "BEGIN{binmode(STDIN);binmode(STDOUT)}" doesn't seem to work, may skip some tests at t/common.p
m line 189.
t/03_ex.t ..................... 1/17 error: member not found
 at C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Archive-Zip-1.39-UHv240\blib\lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 185.
        Archive::Zip::Archive::extractMember(Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x4c8468), "testdir\\cq6T6jDiTJ/testing.txt") called at examples/ext
ract.pl line 34
Extracting testdir\cq6T6jDiTJ/testing.txt from C:\Users\amurty\AppData\Local\Temp\testout-P4oqi.zip failed

t/03_ex.t ..................... 4/17 #   Failed test at t/03_ex.t line 37.
#          got: '65280'
#     expected: '0'
Can't call method "desiredCompressionLevel" on an undefined value at C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Archive-Zip-1.39-UHv240\blib\lib/Archive/Zip/Arc
hive.pm line 257.

#   Failed test at t/03_ex.t line 41.
#          got: '512'
#     expected: '0'
t/03_ex.t ..................... 8/17
#   Failed test at t/03_ex.t line 55.
#          got: 'testdir/cq6T6jDiTJ/testing.txt:100
# '
#     expected: 'testdir\cq6T6jDiTJ/testing.txt:100
# '
error: testdir\cq6T6jDiTJ\testing.txt is neither a file nor a directory
 at C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Archive-Zip-1.39-UHv240\blib\lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 355.
        Archive::Zip::Archive::addFileOrDirectory(Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x458588), "testdir\\cq6T6jDiTJ\\testing.txt") called at exampl
es/selfex.pl line 28

#   Failed test 'extracted\testdir\cq6T6jDiTJ\testing.txt exists'
#   at t/03_ex.t line 69.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '1'
error: Can't rename C:\Users\amurty\AppData\Local\Temp\testout-P4oqi.zip as C:\Users\amurty\AppData\Local\Temp\testout-P4oqi.zbk Permission
denied
 at C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Archive-Zip-1.39-UHv240\blib\lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 472.
        Archive::Zip::Archive::overwriteAs(Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x637a98), "C:\\Users\\amurty\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\testout-P4oqi.zip
") called at C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Archive-Zip-1.39-UHv240\blib\lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 440
        Archive::Zip::Archive::overwrite(Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x637a98)) called at examples/updateTree.pl line 28

t/03_ex.t ..................... 14/17 #   Failed test 'updateTree.pl create'
#   at t/03_ex.t line 78.
#          got: '512'
#     expected: '0'
error: Can't rename C:\Users\amurty\AppData\Local\Temp\testout-P4oqi.zip as C:\Users\amurty\AppData\Local\Temp\testout-P4oqi.zbk Permission
denied
 at C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Archive-Zip-1.39-UHv240\blib\lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 472.
        Archive::Zip::Archive::overwriteAs(Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x4e7a98), "C:\\Users\\amurty\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\testout-P4oqi.zip
") called at C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Archive-Zip-1.39-UHv240\blib\lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 440
        Archive::Zip::Archive::overwrite(Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x4e7a98)) called at examples/updateTree.pl line 28

#   Failed test 'updateTree.pl update'
#   at t/03_ex.t line 81.
#          got: '512'
#     expected: '0'
# Looks like you failed 6 tests of 17.
t/03_ex.t ..................... Dubious, test returned 6 (wstat 1536, 0x600)
Failed 6/17 subtests
t/04_readmember.t ............. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
warning: C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -pe "BEGIN{binmode(STDIN);binmode(STDOUT)}" doesn't seem to work, may skip some tests at t/common.p
m line 189.
t/04_readmember.t ............. ok
t/05_tree.t ................... The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
warning: C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -pe "BEGIN{binmode(STDIN);binmode(STDOUT)}" doesn't seem to work, may skip some tests at t/common.p
m line 189.
t/05_tree.t ................... ok
t/06_update.t ................. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
warning: C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -pe "BEGIN{binmode(STDIN);binmode(STDOUT)}" doesn't seem to work, may skip some tests at t/common.p
m line 189.
t/06_update.t ................. ok
t/07_filenames_of_0.t ......... The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
warning: C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -pe "BEGIN{binmode(STDIN);binmode(STDOUT)}" doesn't seem to work, may skip some tests at t/common.p
m line 189.
t/07_filenames_of_0.t ......... ok
t/08_readmember_record_sep.t .. skipped: Ignoring failing tests on Win32
t/09_output_record_sep.t ...... ok
t/10_chmod.t .................. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
warning: C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -pe "BEGIN{binmode(STDIN);binmode(STDOUT)}" doesn't seem to work, may skip some tests at t/common.p
m line 189.
t/10_chmod.t .................. ok
t/11_explorer.t ............... ok
t/12_bug_47223.t .............. ok
t/13_bug_46303.t .............. ok
t/14_leading_separator.t ...... The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
warning: C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -pe "BEGIN{binmode(STDIN);binmode(STDOUT)}" doesn't seem to work, may skip some tests at t/common.p
m line 189.
t/14_leading_separator.t ...... ok
t/15_decrypt.t ................ ok
t/16_decrypt.t ................ ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/02_main.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 47 Failed: 7)
  Failed tests:  25, 32-34, 38, 46-47
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 141 tests but ran 47.
t/03_ex.t                   (Wstat: 1536 Tests: 17 Failed: 6)
  Failed tests:  4, 6, 10, 13-14, 16
  Non-zero exit status: 6
Files=16, Tests=140,  9 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr +  0.13 sys =  0.22 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/16 test programs. 13/140 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
  PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.39.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.39.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Archive::Zip'.
Failed during this command:
 PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.39.tar.gz                : make_test NO


cpan>
```

Comment: I get the same result here, Windows 7 Pro and Strawberry perl 5.18.2 using `cpanm Archive::Zip`.

Comment: I tried downloading the source and building it and installing it, got the same result. This one failure is preventing me from updating all my modules using the 'install Bundle::CPAN' command.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but on linux, also with 5.20.1

Comment: ditto for FreeBsd and perlbrew 5.20.2

Comment: Fails again for Strawberry Perl 5.24.0 using 'install Bundle::CPAN'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they changed something, because it works now.

```
Running make test
"C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\li
b', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/01_compile.t ................ ok
t/02_main.t ................... ok
t/03_ex.t ..................... ok
t/04_readmember.t ............. ok
t/05_tree.t ................... ok
t/06_update.t ................. ok
t/07_filenames_of_0.t ......... ok
t/08_readmember_record_sep.t .. skipped: Ignoring failing tests on Win32
t/09_output_record_sep.t ...... ok
t/10_chmod.t .................. ok
t/11_explorer.t ............... ok
t/12_bug_47223.t .............. ok
t/13_bug_46303.t .............. ok
t/14_leading_separator.t ...... ok
t/15_decrypt.t ................ ok
t/16_decrypt.t ................ ok
t/17_101092.t ................. ok
t/18_bug_92205.t .............. ok
t/19_bug_101240.t ............. ok
All tests successful.
Files=19, Tests=272, 10 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr +  0.14 sys =  0.23 CPU)
Result: PASS

Archive::Zip is up to date (1.46).
```